# Reading/writing/copying an ArrayBuffer into another ArrayBuffer with an offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-data, arraybuffer

Let's say I have an `ArrayBuffer` which is an `mp4` file. I'd like to create a new `ArrayBuffer` with a few extra bytes to be used as header information, and then store the `mp4` buffer in the remainder of the new `ArrayBuffer`.

```
// ... assume the `data` variable is an existing ArrayBuffer with the contents
// of the mp4 video file.

var ab = new ArrayBuffer(10 + data.byteLength)
var view = new DataView(ab);

view.setInt32(0, 29102); // header information 1
view.setInt32(4, 18282); // header information 2
view.setInt16(8, 576); // header information 3
```

Now, at this point, I can't figure out how to write the contents of `data` into the new `ab` buffer, so that, in the end I have an `ArrayBuffer` which contains 3 groups of numbers in the beginning, along with the entire contents of the video.

I tried using the following:

`view.setInt32(10, data.buffer)`

and although I got no errors, the data was not actually written into the buffer. I was unable to write the video to a file and play it:

```
function readPayload(ab) {
    var view = new DataView(ab);
    console.log(' first header: ' + view.getInt32(0)); // correct
    console.log('second header: ' + view.getInt32(4)); // correct
    console.log(' third header: ' + view.getInt16(8)); // correct
    var data = new Buffer(ab.slice(10));
    console.log('new file size: ' + data.byteLength); // correct length of mp4 file

    var ws = fs.createWriteStream('test.mp4');  // this wrote a corrupt file
    ws.write(data);
    ws.end();
}
```

In the above function, all of the numbers I retrieve are correct, however when I try to write the payload data to a file, the file is the correct size, but it is corrupt.

```
    file size: 5253880
  buffer size: 5253890
-- reading data
 first header: 29102
second header: 18282
 third header: 576
new file size: 5253880
```

So I can't tell whether it's being stored in the new `ArrayBuffer` incorrectly, or whether I'm extracting the buffer incorrectly - but the `test.mp4` that is written does not contain the correct binary data.

Comment: Can't you just do `view.setInt32(10, data)` ? and then get the new ArrayBuffer using `view.buffer`

Comment: @Sachin - I updated my question based on your comment and can't verify whether or not the storing or extraction of the data is the problem.

Comment: @Sachin - in case you're interested in how it can be done, I figured out a solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After more digging I was finally able to piece together a workable solution. This successfully copies the contents of the `mp4` `ArrayBuffer` into the new `ArrayBuffer`, from an offset *(which has the header information)*:

```
new Uint8Array(ab, 0, ab.byteLength).set(new Uint8Array(data), 10);
```

Here I'm creating a view of type `Uint8Array` on the `ArrayBuffer` that also contains the header information *(`ab`)*. Specifying the same size I used to create that `ArrayBuffer`.

With that newly created view, I then call the `.set` function, the first parameter is the original `mp4` `ArrayBuffer` which I *also* give a `Uint8Array` view to, and tell the `set` command to start from offset `10`.

This assigns all of the contents of `data` to `ab` from an offset of `10`.

Comment: Thats a nice way to do it.